# Encrypt and deploy app.config

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, connection-string

I read and tested a lot to find the best practice to encrypt and deploy an `app.config` to different machines. In general, I would like to secure the content of the connection string from third parties and deploy the application to different machines. I will **not** configure each machine manually.

I know there are several ways like:

- Aspnet_Regiis (RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider,
  DPAPIProtectedConfigurationProvider) bound to a machine, user or custom.
  RSA encryption key.
- `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` bound to a machine or user.
- Encrypt the `app.config` at the first execution. Which is not secure.

What do you recommend or what is the best practice to encrypt an `app.config` and provide the application to different machines by a setup or with copy&paste?

Answer (score 12):

**Step 1**  Create an RSA keypair

```
aspnet_regiis -pc yourkey -exp
```

*Step2* Export you key in XML file

```
aspnet_regiis -px yourkey keyfile.xml -pri
```

for each machines

**Step3** Import your container

```
aspnet_regiis -pi yourkey keyfile.xml (see step 2)
```

for each machines

**Step4** Edit machine.config (canonical path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64|32]\v[Version]\Config)

add in section  **configProtectedData** this below element and set **defaultProvider="YourProvider"**

```
<add name="YourProvider"
                type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider,System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt for my infrastucture"

                keyContainerName="yourkey"

                cspProviderName=""
                useMachineContainer="true"
                useOAEP="false" />
```

Then you can encrypt in a machine and paste in other, remember that must give privileges to users with

```
aspnet_regiis -pa yourkey [DOMAIN\USER]
```

The administrators group is already authorized.

For more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2(v=vs.90).aspx

of course this steps you can put in a powershell/batch file

Another way for encrypt a connectionStrings section by code is

```
 var connectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionStrings") 
 if(!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
     connectionStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("YourProvider");
```

In a connected and client/server scenario I propose you a solution that I have adopted in a wide network is of not distribute connection string in app.config but of require the connection's information at a service that can be an web service or a RESTful service after the user authentication.

In step more o less is thus

1. Authenticate user
2. Require connection info at service with username as parameter (HTTPS protocol)
3. a service return connection string
4. App it connect at DB

With this solution you can choose which server the user connects if you have regional server or more server

I hope be helpful

Comment: Does I use the same RSA keypair for each machine? Does every domain user which will execute the application needs privileges for the key?

Comment: Yes, you must use same key on all machines and give the privileges to the only the app pool user i.e. network service or applicatiopoolidentity of the app

Comment: I think thats a fine solution for a server farm. But what if you would like to provide your application to more then 1000 machines and users?

Comment: is your scenario intranet or internet? For users authorization you can use a group, in addition all user in the administrators group are already authorized.

Comment: Generally, I will need it for the intranet. The solution works fine, but I will wait a little bit more. Maybe there is a solution without configuring the client machine. However, thank you very much! I think you have to export the private key too in step 2. It works with `aspnet_regiis -px yourkey keyfile.xml -pri`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I update my post with another possible solution

Comment: Hence, every user with privileges could decrypt the data, right? Thus a user could access the password in a connection string?

Comment: who has access the the RSA container can decrypt the connectionStrings. If you want to avoid this of decrypt operation in your app must impersonate a user authorized in  (only) connection phase (i.e. administrator)  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx Of course if you use the impersonate strategy you can privileges only to a user,

Answer (score 3):

As I already mention in the question, there are many different ways to encrypt a configuration file. For a widely perspective I would like to describe an additional opportunity. I will not describe the concrete implementation, more the concept.

With a custom action in a msi installer you can encrypt the configuration file directly with the Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI). To secure the second entropy you can use an obfuscator. As a result, only the application is able to encrypt the configuration file.

**Advantage**

- Quite secure.
- No machine configuration is necessary.
- Insert the credential during the setup.

**Disadvantage**

- The configuration file is not encrypted in the setup. You have to protect it (permissions).

Please feel free to discuss and give some feedback to this answer.